# How to see size of dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox

The solutions that are online like [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-accounts-billing/How-can-I-see-the-folder-size-on-dropbox-com/td-p/246410) don't work. There is actually no option to "Calculate size", maybe because I slightly over the 2 GB quota? But I don't have that option.

I would like to see which folder and files are taking up my space so I can delete them. There is apparently no easy way to do that.

Comment: Dropbox uses a local folder for duplicate files held on the web; how to handle / check these files depends on your OS. You didn't tell about which OS you have.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has really made this very difficult.

The best solution is to just download the entire dropbox and deal with sizes locally but how to even do that? Because dropbox help tells you to select each folder to download!

The simple solution is to use keyboard. Go "All Files" and press CTRL + A and thankfully that works and it selects all folders and files. Now download and work with the data locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Sync'd the DropBox to you local machine (or machines), the files are here:

C:\Users\username\Dropbox

On my machine, properties of my DropBox folder is about 300 MB (well below the limit) because I do not keep big folders in DropBox.

But the total usage on your machine is in the folder above. I checked two machines where I keep a complete sync and they are both the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox seems to actively make this difficult. Options are syncing/downloading and checking locally. In this case you have to take into account ignored/selective synced folders (if you use these options) making it complicated.

Online it should be possible to calculate the size of a folder one by one see https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/space-storage/file-size. Note that dropbox chose to explicitly forbid calculating the size of multiple folders at once by selecting multiple ones. So you can only do it by hitting the ellipses (...) and selecting `calculate size` one by one for each folder.

The calculate size option should be under `Events` and above `Show in file explorer` and is only visible if you have not already calculated the size for that folder.